# Generate all possible 2 and 3 string combinations from a list in python

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have a following list:

```
mylist = ['car', 'truck', 'ship']
```

Currently I am able to only get all the possible combinations of 2 strings using this:

```
from itertools import combinations
print(list(combinations(mylist,2)))
```

which gives me:

```
[('car', 'truck'), ('car', 'ship'), ('truck', 'ship')]
```

However, one combination is actually all the 3 strings. Thus I would like my outcome to be:

```
[('car', 'truck'), ('car', 'ship'), ('truck', 'ship'), ('car', 'truck', 'ship')]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want all combinations *except* those of length 1?

Comment: why is `('car')` not in your result? what is it you actually need?

Comment: If order is not important, `list(set(combinations(mylist,2)).union(set(combinations(mylist, 3))]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an adjusted case of the powerset. Typically the code for the powerset in Python looks like this:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(it):
    yield from chain.from_iterable(combinations(it, r) for r in range(len(it)+1))
```

You can change it, though, to only accept results within a certain range. In your case, it's from 2 to the 3:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def adjusted_powerset(it):
    yield from chain.from_iterable(combinations(it, r) for r in range(2, 3))
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/E3zW).

If you need it to become more general, play with the `range` parameters. A nice template would be to create a powerset helper:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset_helper(it, start, stop):
    yield from chain.from_iterable(combinations(it, r) for r in range(start, stop+1))

def powerset(it):
    yield from powerset_helper(it, 0, len(it))

def adjusted_powerset(it):
    yield from powerset_helper(it, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this,

```
from itertools import combinations

mylist = ['car', 'truck', 'ship']
result = list()

for r in [2, 3]:
    result.extend(combinations(mylist, r))

print(result)
[('car', 'truck'), ('car', 'ship'), ('truck', 'ship'), ('car', 'truck', 'ship')]
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, another combination is collections containing only one word, as well as the empty set. The set of all possible combinations *n choose k* for all * 0 <= k <= n* is called the *powerset* of the collection.

The documentation page of *itertools* gives an example of how to produce it. I have slightly modified it to accept a *minlength* variable (in your case *minlength=2*)

```
def powerset(iterable, minlength=0):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(minlength, len(s)+1))
```

Comment: This is a good start. Make sure you add a `filter` to this which removes all neither-length-2-nor-3 combinations.

Comment: @erip: thanks for the note, I edited the answer. I just noticed the default case, because it is easy to forget trivial subsets (like 0 and 1 length)

Comment: That's another nice way to do it. +1

Answer (score 1):

[itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) supports list length as an input parameter.

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = range(r)
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

For your case, simply add 2-string and 3-string together:

```
from itertools import combinations
print(list(combinations(mylist,2)) + list(combinations(mylist,3)))
```